# Copy a list to another list

Tags: apex, controller, list, iteration

I have a custom object called skill_Review and I am creating a list in my controller using:

```
 List<Skill_Review__c> skillRev  = new List<Skill_Review__c>
    List<Skill_Review__c> results = [SELECT Id,Name,Skill__c,Level__c FROM Skill_Review__c where Interview__c =:review.id ];
```

I have another list named skillRev of type skill_review_c in my controller. I want to get each field value in result and put it in the skillRev. Basically I would like to clone results list to skillRev. How can I do this? Is there a way to access Skill__c from results in controller like results.Skill_c?

Comment: question is not very clear. but are you looking for this `skillRev.addAll(results)` ? This will add all values if `result` into `skillRev` list

Comment: How can I get Skill__c from results list in my controller?

Comment: Can you post some more relevant code to figure out what you are trying to achieve? otherwise,  skillRev.addAll(results) is sufficient to add value in skillRev assuming it is a controller variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look into  **[documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm)**

You can use **[list.clone()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm#apex_System_List_clone)**

Example

```
List<Skill_Review__c> results = [SELECT Id,Name,Skill__c,Level__c 
                                    FROM Skill_Review__c 
                                     where Interview__c =:review.id ];
    List<Skill_Review__c> skillRev = results .clone();
```

Like @Ashwani said you can use addAll() method here

```
  List<Skill_Review__c> skillRev =new List<Skill_Review__c>();
  skillRev.addAll(skillRev );
```